# Mongoose seeder: Schema hasn't been registered for model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Much like [this unanswered post](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/problem-with-mongooseseeder) I'm having trouble getting [mongoose-seeder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-seeder) to work.

I'm using it as instructed [here](https://wit-hdip-computer-science.github.io/semester-2-ent-web-development/topic-11-seeding/talk-2-seeding/mongo-seeding.pdf):

```
mongoose.connection.on("connected", function() {
  console.log('Mongoose connected');
  const seeder = require('mongoose-seeder');
  const Venue = require('../models/venue');
  seeder.seed(seedData, { dropDatabase: false, dropCollections: true }).then(dbData => {
    console.log('seeded');
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
mongoose.connect(dbUri, () => {
  console.log('Connected');
});
```

This gives me:

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Venue".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Here's my venue model. There's nothing special about it that I can see:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const venueSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Venue', venueSchema);
```

Comment: please post the code for Venue schema

Comment: This looks to me like a bug with the package. Possibly to do with Mongoose version. I've submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/SamVerschueren/mongoose-seeder/pull/15) which fixes this problem for Mongoose 4.x and 5.x.

Comment: May be it is a problem with package but I get this error when I give `ref` for a model and do populate with it

Comment: did you resolve it? Can you post all of the seeder file?

Comment: @Yachi웃 In [my fork of Mongoose seeder](https://github.com/roblevy/mongoose-seeder) this now works. You'll have to `git clone` it, put the directory in your `node_modules` directory and `yarn install` or `npm install` inside the directory to install all the dependencies. Good luck!

Comment: add `new` keyword. `const venueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }
})`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Seedgoose](https://github.com/zhangkaiyulw/seedgoose) instead. This is the ultimate mongoose seeder with smart reference support.